Splitting Time Between Computer Vision/AI and Computational Geometry?
I'm currently working at a private company where my main passion and focus is AI, particularly computer vision. I want a research career in this field and I'm interested in public research. However, due to company needs, I'm also spending a significant portion of my time working on computational geometry projects.
While computational geometry is related to computer vision, the work doesn't involve machine learning and isn't really aligned with current CV state-of-the-art approaches or major research directions. I'm genuinely learning a lot - getting deep into algorithms, optimization techniques, and working with specialized computational geometry frameworks. Some of these skills might transfer over to CV work, but I'm not entirely sure.
My main concern is about future job prospects. The AI/CV field moves incredibly fast, and I wonder if splitting my focus like this might put me at a disadvantage compared to others who are working purely on AI/CV projects. While I appreciate the broader perspective I'm gaining, I can't help but worry if I should be pushing harder to focus exclusively on AI/CV work.
I'd really value any insights from people who have experience working across these related but distinct fields. Has anyone managed to leverage computational geometry experience in their AI/CV career? Or do you think it's better to specialize more narrowly?
Thanks in advance for any advice or perspectives you can share!

This seems to be about the job market, not about academia. The workplace is a better fit: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

You’re very fortunate to have a position allowing you to work in both fields. Are you certain its path doesn’t allow (or require) you to develop into a researcher? The grass is greener, etc.

This is a perennial problem and in a broad sense probably unanswerable. Can only wish you wisdom and a good dose of luck!
